# C# read only on methods best practices?

Tags: c#

I remember someone telling me that setting final whenever applicable is considered good practice in java. Everything not considered to change in any way.

For example:

```
private String final myProperty = "Hello World";

private String final myMethod() {
 return "Hello World";
}
```

Is there an equivalent? Should I use readonly whenever possible, as far as im aware its nearly identical to final. Not sure if its ok to use it in the same way though.

Comment: C#'s `readonly` can only be applied to fields.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever oh I see.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever But still you can make `readonly` properties using only the `get` method.